# Facebook and Cross domain messaging clarification?

Tags: javascript, facebook, cross-domain, facebook-javascript-sdk

I wanted to investigate how the facebook login transfer data to the main page ( mypage) - despite the cross domain boundary limitation.

And so I created a new page with the `FB js sdk` code :

```
FB.login(function (response)
    {
    if (response.authResponse)
        {...
```

It does open the popup :

[image]

But when I investigated to see if I have any Iframes **on my page** ( My code doesn't contain any iframes) :

I saw this :

```
>>$("iframe")
```

result :

```
[
<iframe name=​"fb_xdm_frame_http" frameborder=​"0" allowtransparency=​"true" scrolling=​"no" id=​"fb_xdm_frame_http" aria-hidden=​"true" title=​"Facebook Cross Domain Communication Frame" tab-index=​"-1" src=​"http:​/​/​static.ak.facebook.com/​connect/​xd_arbiter.php?version=24#channe…l_path=%2FWebSite2%2FHTMLPage3.htm%3Ffb_xd_fragment%23xd_sig%3Df5252874%26" style=​"border:​ none;​">​…​</iframe>​
, 
<iframe name=​"fb_xdm_frame_https" frameborder=​"0" allowtransparency=​"true" scrolling=​"no" id=​"fb_xdm_frame_https" aria-hidden=​"true" title=​"Facebook Cross Domain Communication Frame" tab-index=​"-1" src=​"https:​/​/​s-static.ak.facebook.com/​connect/​xd_arbiter.php?version=24#cha…l_path=%2FWebSite2%2FHTMLPage3.htm%3Ffb_xd_fragment%23xd_sig%3Df5252874%26" style=​"border:​ none;​">​…​</iframe>​
]
```

I read that they are used for the cross domain.

But the question is why are they **on MY PAGE**  ?

They should be somewhere on facebook internal pages!

I'm saying it because I know that the *Iframe technique* works like this  :

[image]

As you can see  -  the internal Iframe creates *another* iframe with the `SRC` value from query string (the value is the top page url actually)  , and then  , with JS on both pages  +  `URL => JS`  trigger functions , we can do :

`top.sendData({...})`

What am I missing ?

- How does the data is being passed from the FB login to my page ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I'm the engineer who designed the current infrastructure for Cross-Domain Messaging in the Facebook JS SDK, so maybe I can shed some light on things here.

This setup might seem a bit unorthodox and confusing to some, but it's really quite elegant, if I might say so myself :)

---

Depending on whether the page is HTTP or HTTPS, the JS SDK will create two iframes, pointing to the xd_arbiter.php resource, which is served from a *.facebook.com domain. Since it sets `document.domain = 'facebook.com'`, these can communicate with other resources on facebook.com that does the same.

These resources, the proxies, gets passes some information through the fragment, to give them dynamic capabilities, but are otherwise 100% static and cached by your browser - so these are really fast to load.

What happens next is that a Cross-Domain Messaging link is established between the host page, and each of the iframes (the proxies). This means that from now on, the host page can communicate to a HTTPS page on facebook.com, and if the host page is HTTP, it can also communicate with a HTTP page on facebook.com.

How this link works across browsers is a more complex matter, but it's all abstracted into a channel, much like you can see with [easyXDM](http://github.com/oyvindkinsey/easyXDM).

---

Now, whenever the JS SDK creates a new window on facebook.com, either as a popup, or as an iframe, instead of having to set up a fresh communication channel between the host page and each window, the new windows can utilize the existing proxy, paying no cost in setup.

When needing to send messages to the host page, these will use `(window.opener || window.parent).frames['fb_xdm_frame_' + location.protocol.replace(':', '')` to get a handle to the proxy, and similarly, the proxy can use `parent.frames[some_name]` to get a handle to any sibling iframes on the page, as long as the right proxy (HTTP or HTTPS) was used.

For us, this basically means that the concern about how to communicate cross-domain is isolated to the JS SDK and its resources - any services we build on top of this can rely on a very simple api of `send_this_message(message, origin)` and it will 'magically' end up on the other end, if allowed by the origin checks we have in place.

I hope this answers your question!

---

(xd_arbiter.php can also serve as a redirect target, where it will use it's sibling proxies to relay the message).

Comment: Words cannot describe my thankfulness. However I still have a question. Both FB's I frames can connect ( one to each other because of `document.domain=...` ) via `window.opener.frames[...]` but after they do that , how do they **transfer** information to the **host** page ? its a different origin !

Comment: I mean,  do those iframes use the  `hidden Iframe technique` (like in my question) , or do they do `postMessage` or....what? how do they say to the host PAge : `"Hey hoster  , this is the user information :..."`

Comment: Ive been sitting on this whole day. and got managed to do this : http://i.stack.imgur.com/zVS3M.jpg   please reply if it's the same ...

Comment: Sean , can you please answer my comments ?

Comment: "How this link works across browsers is a more complex matter, but it's all abstracted into a channel, much like you can see with easyXDM."

Comment: i think the postmessage api can be used to communicate from the iframe to the js sdk living outside the iframe

Comment: @SeanKinsey Can you please have a look at this [other cross origin question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25862467/cors-csrf-clarification) ?

Comment: @SeanKinsey I learned about this iframe when I got an error in Google Webmaster Tools, under HTML Improvements, where it showed I had pages with duplicate <title> tags. What can be done about this?

Comment: @Ben, there's nothing that needs to be done about this - at worst it's a misclassification from the tool's side.

Comment: Is there any way to disable this? This is causing CORS violation errors in an application where the Facebook JS SDK is loaded _and_ the application accesses `window.frames`.

Comment: @fritzmg, what exactly is it that you want to disable? If you could provide an example of where what the JS SDK is triggering this alert, and a description of any restrictions you've put in place, then we could take a look at how to avoid this.

Comment: @SeanKinsey the problem is described in more detail here: https://github.com/codefog/contao-news_categories/issues/100#issuecomment-286737531 It probably needs to be addressed by Contao and the affected extensions though.

Comment: @fritzmg, this does indeed look like an issue external to the JS SDK. In general it is never safe to make any assumptions about the browser, such as all iframes being your own - a number of browser extensions would end up triggering the same.

Comment: Yes, I agree :).

Answer (score 0):

I think the concept can be simple based on if you're ie8+ in your code.

CORS can be used to communicate cross domain.  Make sure the right headers are set at your host and you're good.

Or, create an iframe, set its src as something that passes information to a dynamic script.  Process the information.  Return JS code to the iframe that uses postMessage to communicate with the outside window.