# CORS & CSRF - clarification?

Tags: cross-domain, cors, csrf

*I've been using CORS for a long time for allowing ajax responses to be read from another domain.*

I had a discussion with a colleague about CORS and- while discussion - he supplied an example which I thought was irrelevant to the CORS issue.

He said :

> the same origin policy is so that if you're logged into your bank and
>   go on my site, I can't exploit your credentials and make a cross
>   origin request to your bank and send myself money.

But that's seemed to me as a pure csrf attack , which not relates to CORS ( unless reading the ajax's response ) :

So I said :

> About the thing you wrote : *"if you're logged into your bank and go on
>   my site, I can't exploit your credentials and make a cross origin
>   request to your bank and send myself money."*........If I go to your
>   site and you run ajax request to the bank : the bank server WILL see
>   the request . and if you run ajax request withCredentials , the
>   cookies WILL be sent **I think you're talking about CSRF attack to block**

Then  he said :

> no, CSRF is something different. CSRF is when I sneak an image or a
>   button to make a request on your site to bypass the same origin
>   policy.

(IMHO - no !  - you don't have to sneak anything to my site. CSRF is when you make an unwanted  request on my behalf to do evil things - you don't have to sneak anything )

So I told him :

> You can send me html form which posts to a known location for example
>   - bank And so the solution is cookie / hidden field match to a server value So if the malicious site is doing a request - it won't have the
>   hidden field value Your example - talks about csrf attack . The part
>   where you cant read the response - is the only cors part.
>   **im just saying that the bank example was a bit irrelevant here** ( to the CORS discussion)

He said :

> Of course it was relevant

Finally I said :

IMO - CORS was designed for ( example) :

> For a.com to run ajax requests to facebook to get all friends - its
>   where comes more relevant

**Question :**

For Learning , and getting better and In order to solve this confusion and feel at peace -  was I right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that for his attack to be possible, given the premise that any mutations would be issued using POST/PUT/DEL, your bank would have to enable CORS in order for the XHR to be allowed (the preflight checks would fail otherwise) AND be susceptible to a CSRF attack.

Of course, if the bank was susceptible to CSRF, a simple form post would do the trick as well.

So you are right. CORS does not prevent CSRF, all it does is *relax* the restrictions enforced by the Same Origin Policy.